# Does a limit of a sequence exist in compact set

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, compactness

I am confused about the following statement in someone's paper:

> Since the probability simplex is **compact**, the sequence $\{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [d]}$ belonging to the probability simplex for any $T$ converges to a vector $w$ in the probability simplex when $T\to\infty$. $T$ is an index and we assume it is any integer greater than 1. $d$ is the dimension of the probability simplex.

You can image $\{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [d]}=[a^{(T)}_1, a^{(T)}_2, ..., a^{(T)}_d]$ is a probability vector but each element may change over time $T$.

However, let's consider 2-dimension probability simplex, I am confused about whether the following sequence would converge to a vector in probability simplex or not:

> If $\{a^{(1)}_n\}_{n\in [2]}$ = [1, 0], $\{a^{(1)}_n\}_{n\in [2]}$ = [0, 1], $\{a^{(3)}_n\}_{n\in [2]}$ = [1, 0], ... and so on. That is, when T is even,  $\{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [2]} = [0, 1]$ but when T is odd, $\{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [2]}$ = [1, 0].

So for any $T\geq 1$, $\{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [2]}$ is a probaiblity vector, but can we say $\{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [2]}$ converges to a vector $w$ in the probability simplex? can we say $\lim_{T\to\infty} \{a^{(T)}_n\}_{n\in [2]} = w$? If the answer is yes, is it related to the compactness of the probability simplex?

Comment: It’s hard to say without more context (you should include a reference to the actual paper). In general compactness doesn’t imply a sequence converges, but it does (often, presumably in this scenario) imply that when a sequence does converge, it converges to a point in the set, not to something outside it.

Comment: But compactness imply there is a subsequence of the original sequence that can converges to a point in the compact set?

Comment: Yes (often, presumably in this scenario), compactness implies any sequence in the set has a subsequence that converges to a point in the set. (In general, this property is called sequential compactness.) This in turn implies that if a sequence in the set converges, it converges to a point in the set, since if a sequence converges to a unique point then all subsequences converge to that same point.